# Background color for more than 5 tabs Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a Xamarin form for android that I set the background color for tabs on a tabbed page as follow:

```
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Burlywood"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#ffeacf"
        BarBackgroundColor="#693100"
        BarTextColor="BurlyWood"
```

The first 4 tabs show exactly the right colors but, the next 2 tabs, under the MORE menu, show a white background.
May I get help please on how to change the background and text colors for the additional 2 tabs?
Thank you.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oRXj.png)

Comment: @From Shell [custom render](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b77de4d77da6d404a634eea32d88785d43ff3a3a/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen/Shell/ShellItemRenderer.cs#L344), there is one panel pop up when we click More tab, it is not BottomNavigation bar, I can not find a way to replace this panel or set background color, you can feedback this request on github , I think it is new feature.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xamarin.Forms you can set the NavigationBar Background color via the Code behind in the constructor method:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```