# Change Background color of tabs popup opened on click of more button/icon in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I have a Xamarin form for android that I set the background color for tabs at the time of creating the tabs from code behind. The first 4 tabs show exactly the right colors but, the next 3 tabs, under the MORE menu, show a white background. May I get help please on how to change the background and text colors for the additional 3 tabs?

[[Background color works well for initial 4 tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ4kx.png)] but does not behaves the same with tabs that are opened on the click of more (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRZLm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created a project and used `TabbedPage`. It shows the same situation happened to you.

Then I tried to Modify its background and text colors by `TabbedPageRenderer` but failed. There are no relevant override methods to achieve it.

I searched relevant cases about it. You can refer to them:

**Case1:** [How to change name of "More" tab on tabbedPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111379/how-to-change-name-of-more-tab-on-tabbedpage). It tells about Changing name of "More" by `TabbedPageRenderer`.

**Case2:** [Background color for more than 5 tabs Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791591/background-color-for-more-than-5-tabs-xamarin-forms). It involved:

> From Shell [custom render](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b77de4d77da6d404a634eea32d88785d43ff3a3a/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen/Shell/ShellItemRenderer.cs#L344), there is one panel pop up when we click More tab, it is not BottomNavigation bar, I can not find a way to replace this panel or set background color, you can feedback this request on github , I think it is new feature.

It's the source code of Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen, but I did not find the code of Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.

In addition, if you can accept this effect: [Xamarin tabbed page slide tab bar instead of "More" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55455643/xamarin-tabbed-page-slide-tab-bar-instead-of-more-button). It can help you.